# TextMate does not allow accessing menu bar using the keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

TextMate does not allow access to menu items by the keyboard. As soon as the menu bar is activated, TextMate editor reclaims the focus. So no opportunity to select the menus. I have tried various key combinations by setting

Keyboard > Shortcuts > Move focus to the menubar

However TextMate just immediately steals back focus after I press the combination. So it is impossible to access the menus (short of using the frickin' mouse…)

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: What version (exactly) of TextMate? What version of OS X? I tried v1.5.11 and the current 2.0-alpha on OS X Mavericks 10.9.2, and both let me set focus to the menubar with the OS X system default keyboard shortcut of Ctrl-F2. Well, I had to hit Fn-Ctrl-F2 on my rMBP so that F2 acted as F2 instead of increasing the backlight brightness.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this. First thing I did when switching to mac-os was to remap the keystroke from Ctl-f2 to Command-<either ; or '>.  Reason: too difficult to get to Ctl-F2 when I use it hundreds times daily.

Comment: Please post your update as an Answer and then select your own Answer as correct (click the check mark to turn it green). Super User encourages this behavior when you find your own solution, so that other people see that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I tried a few other key combos and found one that worked. I had tried Command-; and Command-' (both did not work). But Command-. does appear to work.

First thing I did when switching to mac-os was to remap the keystroke from Ctl-f2 to Command-. Reason: too difficult to get to Ctl-F2 when I use it hundreds times daily.